# Firebase Firestore, how to snatch the latest (new) object change in Collection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Chat conversation and what I'm trying to do is get the `Date object` from `ChatMessagesCollection` in database (Last message with `timestamp` ). I have serious doubts if using `orderBy()` is the right way in this situation, because as I imagine it will `Query` the whole `Collection` everytime, and I need only the latest record everytime it pops out. Is there a way to snap latest change and get it's value not querying whole collection and sorting it?

Post scriptum:

Having it catched at `db.set(map)` is not an option, because I need the latest `messageTime` no matter which user is the sender.

Edit:

```
chats.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                      // from newest document, get("MessageTime")
                }
            });
```

Is it possible to try implement it this way? I tried to have a bite on this in many ways but i see no other options unless going through `Query.sortBy()`.

Comment: What exactly are you doing currently to get the date you're looking for?  How are you measuring that it's not efficient, as you imagine?

Comment: In my logic the way it works is it takes all documents everytime, right? so 1. query XXX messages, sortBy -> Latest. and repeat it everytime there is new message sounds really inefficent

Comment: I am trying to implement something like EventListener() and get the latest change everytime, but Iam struggling to do that, I will edit post and put some more insight with code in a second

Comment: @DougStevenson if You could be so kind, please, let me know if You think the querying it "Query query = chats.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1);" is the right way by Your opinion?

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe someone will benefit from it someday.

```
chats.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot snapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    for (DocumentChange documentChange : snapshot.getDocumentChanges())
                    {
                        Object date =  documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("date");
                    }
                }
```